# SQL - Combine custom date range with hourly data to hourly trading volumes

Tags: sql, datetime, hour

I am very new to SQL. I am facing an issue with my query in relation to hourly traded volumes.

I've already made a query to extract hourly volumes within custom date range, but database only consists of hours with actual traded volumes - it looks like this:

```
07/03/2020 09:00    2
07/03/2020 13:00    5
07/03/2020 14:00    10
07/03/2020 18:00    10
07/03/2020 22:00    12
```

What I want to do is to present this volumes for entire day (in this example for 7/3/2020), whether there were some traded volumes in specific hours or not. Hours with no traded volume should have zeros.

I've also succesfully made a query of hourly timeframe for 7/3/2020 :

```
 DECLARE @minDateTime AS DATETIME;
 DECLARE @maxDateTime AS DATETIME;

SET @minDateTime = '2020-03-07 01:00:00';
SET @maxDateTime = '2020-03-07 23:00:00';

;
WITH Dates_CTE
     AS (SELECT @minDateTime AS Dates
         UNION ALL
         SELECT Dateadd(hh, 1, Dates)
         FROM   Dates_CTE
         WHERE  Dates < @maxDateTime)

SELECT *
FROM   Dates_CTE
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `dates_cte`, you want a `left join`:

```
SELECT d.datetimecol, COALESCE(t.val, 0)
FROM d LEFT JOIN
     trades t
     ON t.datetimecol = d.datetimecol;
```

`dates` doesn't make much sense to me as the name of a column with a single date.  You could call it `datetime`, but that conflicts with the name of a type.  I might just call it `dt`.